# GNU screen: how do I use :aclumask to set permissions to unknown users?

Tags: permissions, users, gnu-screen

#### Context

I often create a multiuser GNU screen session for demonstration purposes.  I do it by creating a named session with:

```
screen -S tutorial
```

And then performing

```
^A:multiuser on
^Aaclchg student1,student2,student3,... -wx "#?"
```

And that works, the students can connect with `screen -r grochmal/tutorial` and can see what I do.  (It even locks their PTS 'cause they do not have permission for `^Ad`).

#### Question

What I'd like to do though is to setup `aclumask` so I could make my life easier since I sometimes forget to use `aclchg` and use `acladd` (and a funny student can write swear words on the terminal).

According to how I understand `man screen` the following should be equivalent to what I do above:

```
screen -S tutorial
^A:multiuser on
^A:aclumask ?-wx
^A:acladd student1,student2,student3,...
```

And then I could add the `aclumask ?-wx` to my `.screenrc` and never worry again about funny students.

Unfortunately that is not the case, and the `aclumask` line seems to have no effect on the permissions granted by `acladd`.  I must be doing something wrong.

What is the proper way of using `aclumask` with users that are not yet known to screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP got me to find the last bits of what I needed for my configuration, seeing it's a old question I stumbled in here and found little examples of it elsewhere so figure I could drop my solution here~ I found in the umask it's reading right->left as well between the | if you like to add permission for one and remove from all other try in .screenrc

```
aclchg * -w "#?"
aclchg root -w+w "#?"
aclumask [ -wx | root+wx ]
```

Comment: After living with the limitations for 5 years i took me another 1 year to see the answer.  Indeed, `aclumask` can do both permissions at the same time, albeit i went with `aclumask [ ?-wx | root+wx ]` in the end